# React Testing Library TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

i have react class component that have event

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.monthRef = React.createRef();
    this.yearRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      moIndexActive: props.initialMonth - 1,
      yeIndexActive: years.findIndex(y => y === `${props.initialYear}`),
    };
  }
//some code blablabla
// this error occur in this line bellow
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.monthRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll');
    this.yearRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll');
  }
```

this component used in functional component,
when i test the functional component there is error message
[image]

i am using React Testing Library for test this, i already searched on google but not yet found solution for this, please help me.
if there is any way to mock the **removeEventListener** on react testing library or Jest.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `removeEventListener` needs two arguments, `type` and `listener`.
`type` specifies the type of event for which to remove an event listener and
`listener` is the EventListener function of the event handler to remove from the event target.

So try to put a `null` in the place of `listener` like this

**`this.monthRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll',null)`**

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

alfan-juniyanto,

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong -- your call to the method `removeEventListener('scroll')`, in your `componentWillUnmount()` function, is expecting two parameters:

1. The event to stop listening to,
2. The current event handler that you had previously registered when you called `addEventListener` (which doesn't appear to be in the code snippet you supplied).

For more information, you can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

However, to specifically answer your question, you should pass a pointer to the event handler that you used in the `addEventListener` cycle.

If you just want to make this error message stop for the purposes of your test, you could do something like this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    const _fnEmptyFunctionPointer = ()=>{};
    this.monthRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', _fnEmptyFunctionPointer);
    this.yearRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', _fnEmptyFunctionPointer);
  }
```

The code snippet I provided above simply just passes an empty function as the second (**required**) parameter for the removeEventListener method (really however, like I said previously, you should be passing the pointer to the original function you registered for the listener).

Hope this helps at least explain whats going on with that error you recieved.

Good luck!